# How to select multi elements on aggregate model Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have 2 models loaded into Viewer , when i try to loop through these models and use this method **select(dbids, model, selectionType)** to select multi elements from both model but it only highlight *(blue color)* elemens on the last model. Is it possible to highlight all of these elements at the same time ?
Because i also need to add or remove what i have selected by holding ctrl key so i need to make all of them highligh.
I follow this tutorial to get elemens 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-simpler-extension
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the other post has replied the question. Shortly speaking: After Forge Viewer 4.0, try the code below:

```
var selections = [
 {
   model: targetModel,
   ids: dbIds
  }
];
viewer.impl.selector.setAggregateSelection( selections );
```

Please check if it helps.
[Forge Viewer Select in a multi-model context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614588/forge-viewer-select-in-a-multi-model-context)